# Using Powershell parameters in pipe command

Tags: git, powershell

I have this Powershell script which iterates through this folder's directories and runs `git log`.

However I cannot figure out how to get the `$author` parameter through to the `git` command.

```
Param(
  [string]$author,
  [string]$since
)
Get-ChildItem | ? { $_.PSIsContainer } | % { Push-Location $_.FullName; Write-Host "--" (Get-Location);`
git --no-pager log --author=$author --since='1 friday ago' --until='now' --format='%Cgreen%cr%Creset %s%Creset' --graph --decorate;`
Pop-Location }
```

Comment: What do you get when you invoke the script?

Comment: The list of folder names... I'm looking into it being a quotes issue now.

Comment: Yes, you should definitely pass the `$author` argument in quotes.

Comment: If I don't pass the command then I get all commits which leads suggests the `$author` is actually getting though

Comment: Yes I was passing it through quoted since the start. I'm checking out the `git` command to see if putting quotes like : `--author="$author"`

Comment: Still no luck, tried `.\standup.ps1 --author '\"Matthew Canty\"'` but that's getting to complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given this script:

```
# Log.ps1
Param(
    [string]$author
)

Get-ChildItem -Directory | % { Push-Location $_.FullName; git --no-pager log --author=$author; Pop-Location }
```

Invoking it like this yields the correct result:

```
.\Log.ps1 "SomeAuthor"
```